# Auto change font size for different iPhone devices

Tags: ios, fonts

Is it possible to set different `UILabel`s' font sizes based on the different iPhone device size for an entire application?

Answer (score -1):

I am using custom class of each control for this purpose

```
    class Label: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var iPhoneFontSize:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            overrideFontSize(fontSize: iPhoneFontSize)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 2.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    public var borderColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

   private func overrideFontSize(fontSize:CGFloat){
        let currentFontName = self.font.fontName
        var calculatedFont: UIFont?
        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let height = bounds.size.height
        switch height {
        case 480.0: //Iphone 3,4,SE => 3.5 inch
            calculatedFont = UIFont(name: currentFontName, size: fontSize * 0.7)
            self.font = calculatedFont
            break
        case 568.0: //iphone 5, 5s => 4 inch
            calculatedFont = UIFont(name: currentFontName, size: fontSize * 0.8)
            self.font = calculatedFont
            break
        case 667.0: //iphone 6, 6s, 7, 7s => 4.7 inch
            calculatedFont = UIFont(name: currentFontName, size: fontSize * 0.9)
            self.font = calculatedFont
            break
        case 736.0: //iphone 6+, 6s+, 7+, 7s+ => 5.5 inch
            calculatedFont = UIFont(name: currentFontName, size: fontSize)
            self.font = calculatedFont
            break
        default: // New devices
            calculatedFont = UIFont(name: currentFontName, size: fontSize)
            self.font = calculatedFont
            break
        }

    }
}
```

Then in  Storyboard set iPhoneFontSize property value for highest resolution as seen in screenshot below.

[image: Storyboard Setup]